# Deserializing JSON into python Class / Object

Tags: python, json, class, object

I am fairly new to python and need help taking a json file and incorporating
it into the **init** in a class to be used through out, but I am getting the error below and don't understand why. I have a build a few classes before and this seems to look the same.

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'zipcode'`

I have a separate json file called `config.json` that I have changed some information in (i.e. location and api key), but other than that, this is what I am working with.

`config.json:`

```
{
    "unit_system":"metric",

    "location_information":{
        "country_code":"US",
        "country_name":"United States",
        "city":"New York City",
        "state":"New York",
        "postal":10001
    },

    "api_keys":{
        "weather_api_key":"97a484e1039b7a0779b59f2e57e597a3"
    }
}
```

`weather.py`

```
class weather:
    """weather retrieving app"""

    def __init__(self, data):
        """initialize attributes for weather app"""

        self.unit_system = data['unit_system']
        #unit system

        self.country_code = data['location_information']['country_code']
        self.zipcode = data['location_information']['postal']
        #location information

        self.api_key = data['api_keys']['weather_api_key']
        #api key informaation

    def get_update(self):

        threading.Timer(5.0, w.get_update).start()
        #runs get_update every 5 seconds

        #get weather information
        weather_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=' \
        + str(self.zipcode) + ',' \
        + self.country_code + '&appid=' \
        + self.api_key

        weather_request = requests.get(weather_url)
        weather_data = weather_request.json()
        temp_k = float(weather_data['main']['temp'])

        #determine unit system conversions
        if self.unit_system == 'english':

            temp = (temp_k - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32

        elif self.unit_system == 'metric':

            temp = temp_k - 273.15

        print(temp)
        #return(temp)

import threading
import requests
import json

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

w = weather(config)

w.get_update()
```

Comment: You have to construct a `weather` object by passing it a `data`, like `w = weather(config)`. Then you can call `w.get_update()`. What you're doing is calling the `weather.update` method and asking it to use `config` as a `weather` instance, which it isn't, so you get errors.

Comment: @abarnert, Thank you for the response, that was a quick oversight on my part. I have updated the code so it works properly and pulls updates every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line and put these lines at the bottom. The first line creates an instance of class weather named weather_obj. You can then call the get_update using weather_obj

```
weather_obj = weather(config)
weather_obj.get_update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The scipt you have provided seems to be working.
 [a screenshot of my output(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CfoN.png)